# Use Perl Style Guide rules

Tags: perl, optimization, coding-style

My task is to transfer the "Perl Style Guide" rules to the following code:

http://kulnet.kuleuven.be/perlcourse/perlingo.html

Does anyone see any rules, which I do not follow so far? (Head and function descriptions are missing intentionally.)

$lnp, $pst1, $pst2 is set in config.pl.

Thanks.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

require config;

MAIN: {
   $lnp->execute( );
   while( @data = $lnp->fetchrow_array( ) ) {
      my ( $sn, $en, $portDate, $rcvCarrier, $originCarrier ) = @data;
      my ( @list ) = ();  
      if ( $en =~ /^$/ ) {
         @list = ( $sn );
      }
      else {
         @list = &calc( $sn...$en );
      }
      foreach my $prefix( @list ) {
         my $user = join "", $cc, $ndc, $prefix;  
         $pst1->execute( $user, 1 );
         if ( $rcvCarrier =~ /^$/ ) {
            next;
         }
         if ( $rcvCarrier eq $originCarrier ) {
            next;
         }
         $pst2->execute( $user, $rcvCarrier, $portDate, 1 );
      }
   }
}

sub calc {
   my( @data ) = @_;
   my( @new ) = ( );
   my( %test );
   for my $item ( @data ) {
      my( $suffix ) = chop( $item );
      $test{$item}{$suffix}++;
   }
   for my $base ( keys %test ) {
      if ( scalar( keys %{$test{$base}} ) == 10) {
         push @new, $base;
         next;
      }

      push @new, $base.$_ for keys %{$test{$base}};
   }
   if ( $#new < $#data ) {
      return calc( @new );
   }
   return @new;
}
```

Comment: "Perl Best Practices" and "Modern Perl" seem to disagree with the guides. Why should we try to apply something that looks dated?

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better site to post this question

Answer (score 3):

You are using 3 spaces of indentation instead of the dictated 4 spaces.

Your global variables (that you say are set by config.pl) should start with an upper-case letter; you also need to declare them; the code as it stands won't compile.